# Flash embed code works except in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, flash, embed

Flash ain't my thing. What am I missing? I'm getting these boxes in Internet Explorer.

```
<object width="100" height="65"  >
<param name="wmode" value="<?php echo $entry_user_fish;?>">
<embed src="<?php echo $entry_user_fish;?>" width="100" height="65" wmode="transparent" >   </embed>
</object>
```

[image]

Edit: A little more Info: The php values to to a SWF which works in every browser but IE. IE/ flash says 'movie not loaded on each flash object and the progress bar says 14 items remaining, so its not downloading them correctly. The white boxes are flash objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to use:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"> 
<param name="movie" value="moviename.swf">
```

Answer (score 0):

1). Use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to do embedding, otherwise you will drive yourself absolutely bonkers.

2). `wmode="transparent"` is the devil - only use it if you really, REALLY need to. It kills performance, doesn't play nice with the rest of the page, and generally angers your users. Use "window" or "opaque" if you can get away with it.

3). This line looks wrong:

```
<param name="wmode" value="<?php echo $entry_user_fish;?>">
```

Probably don't want to be setting it to the user's fish name.

4). Or the problem might be here:

```
<embed src="<?php echo $entry_user_fish;?>"
```

Hard to know without knowing what those PHP directives evaluate to, but unless $entry_user_fish is "something.swf" it's not going to work.

Comment: Thanks, trying this all now. I need the flash files to be transparent, is this the only way to do it? Your suggestions gave me black boxes.

Comment: If you actually need a transparent background, then yeah, that's the only way.

Comment: Sigh, in that case I can't help you as I'm not familiar with IE's bizarro support for embed/object tags (which are themselves hacks). SWFObject will fix that for you, or perhaps another answer can.